# Angular 13 - FirebaseError: The Cloud Firestore API is not available for Firestore in Datastore Mode database

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have an angular 8 app integrated into firebase chat which uses datastore. I am integrating the same chat into an angular 13 project but the new angular/fire uses firstore API. I have done the necessary configurations but I get the following error when I try to retrieve messages.

Error:

> Firestore (9.8.2): Could not reach Cloud Firestore backend. Connection failed 1 times. Most recent error: FirebaseError: [code=failed-precondition]: The Cloud Firestore API is not available for Firestore in Datastore Mode database projects/xyz/databases/(default).

Code:

```
loadMessages = (key: any): Observable<any[]> => {
  const parsePhrase = `/issue_chat/${key}/${key}`;
  const chatCollection = collection(this.firestore, parsePhrase);
  return collectionData(chatCollection);
};
```

My research shows that Firestore in Datastore Mode doesn't support the Cloud Firestore API, which is necessary for AngularFire to communicate with Firestore.

How do I go about this?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you created a database in classic Datastore mode, so you can't use the Firestore API on it.

If you want to use the Firestore API, create a database in Firestore's native mode. You'll need to create a new database for this; there is no way to convert the mode of a database once it's been created.

Comment: Can the code be refactored to work with Firestore in Datastore Mode?

Comment: I don't think there's any official client-side JavaScript SDK for Datastore: https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/reference/libraries.